# Eclipse forcibly adds -k to C++ build command arguments

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Whenever I edit to remove `-k`option from build command line of my C++ project (Project->Properties->C/C++ Build -> Build command), Eclipse adds it back upon saving properties. How to defeat this?

Comment: Are you using the "external make" option? It's obsolete for NDK builds. Install the ADT bundle or plugin from http://developer.android.com and you get android gcc toolchain and builder that has `ndk-build` as default build command. On Windows this will all work without cygwin.

Comment: I am using `ndk-build`. How is this relevant, though?

Comment: With the latest ADT you can create an Android project with Native support. For such project, if you look at Properties/C++ Build/Builder settings, you will see `ndk-build` as _default build command_. On the other hand, you can create a **makefile** project, and set "ndk-build" as an override for the default build command **make**. Now, for the latter type of projects you may check or uncheck "Stop on first build error" on the _second tab_ (Behavior) of the same dialog. When the checkbox is off, **-k** is automatically added to whatever command you have in the first tab. Isn't it relevant?

Comment: I see you (or somebody else) changed the tags for this question. So, if it is about generic C++ project, my answer about NDK is really irrelevant. Anyway, the answer for this case is in the previous comment: **-k** is controlled by a checkbox on the second tab.

Comment: @AlexCohn: Thanks! It is indeed relevant and answers the question :)

Comment: So, with your permission, I'll post this as a new answer to close the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For generic C++ projects, you may check or uncheck "Stop on first build error" on the second tab (**Behavior**) of the **Properties/C++ Build/Builder settings** dialog. When the checkbox is off, `-k` is automatically added to whatever command you have in the first tab.

Note that for Android NDK projects, there is now a new ADT plugin which you can get as an ADT bundle or plugin from http://developer.android.com. For such project, if you look at **Properties/C++ Build/Builder settings**, you see `ndk-build` as default build command, and the checkbox on the second tab is disabled, therefore `-k` will never be appended to the command.

You can still create a **makefile** project using the Android toolchain, and set "ndk-build" as an override for the default build command make. With this, you can get `-k` on or off.